# IllegalMonitorStateException raised with explicit lock/condition

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I want to have such kind of work flow using explicit lock/condition variables (It's a course project which mandates this style.): A is the main class, it asks B to do some job from time to time. B has a worker class C which constantly queries B about new jobs to do and do it. After C finishes, it will call A's callback function to notify A the job is done.

However when I try to run the program, I get an IllegalMonitorStateException, when the callback() is trying to notify the doit() function.

```
exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
        at Test$A.callback(Test.java:49)
        at Test$C.run(Test.java:115)
```

I looked at the javadoc and some Q&A about this exception, but still no idea why I get this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

public class Test {
    public class A
    {
        private ReentrantLock lock;
        private Condition cond;
        private boolean bool;
        private B b;
        public A()
        {
            this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
            this.cond = lock.newCondition();
            b = new B(this);
            bool = false;
        }

        public void doit()
        {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                b.letgo();
                while (!bool) {
                    System.out.println("A::doit() Block.");
                    cond.awaitUninterruptibly();
                }
                System.out.println("A::doit() Done.");
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void callback() {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                bool = true;
                cond.notify();
                System.out.println("A::callback() done.");
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        private C c;
        private ReentrantLock lock;
        private Condition cond;
        private boolean bool;
        public B(A a)
        {
            this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
            this.cond = lock.newCondition();
            bool = false;
            c = new C(a, this);
            c.start();
        }

        public void letgo()
        {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                bool = true;
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void get()
        {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                while (!bool) {
                    cond.awaitUninterruptibly();
                }
                bool = false;
                return;
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public class C extends Thread
    {
        private A a;
        private B b;

        public C(A a, B b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while (true) {
                b.get();
                a.callback();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.test1();
    }

    public void test1()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.doit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is `at Test$A.callback(Test.java:49)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`signal()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal()) method on `Condition` in place of `notify()`.

While you can successfully `synchronize` on a `Condition` instance, and then use the traditional `wait()` and `notify()` methods, you might as well just use an `Object` if you aren't using the extended capabilities of the concurrent classes.

`Condition` was intended to be used with the equivalent methods `await()` and `signal()`, and their enhanced variants.